# Spring boot Operations tracker?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-application-insights, spring-boot-actuator

Im building an application that the client wants to keep track of everything that happens. For example: if User A adds something to his profile info, or creates a project or assigns another employee to a project, the system must know something like this "2021-04-02 19:04:41 - A - assigned B to project #projectName".
Basically a timestamp, followed by the user in session by the security context and then a small description of what he did. I ve been investigating with azure application insights and spring actuator and my question is: Is there any way to do this? Im considering creating a sql "LOG table" that keeps track of the stuff that's happening and allows queries by users, i guess the real question is, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You can use [custom event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent) provided by application insights, but you need to manage the context by yourself in the code, then you can search for the logs in azure portal. This solution could avoid creating extra table in database. But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

With azure application insights, you don't need to create a 'LOG table' in your database, you can go to azure portal to view the traces and other logs.

Ms provides codeless feature for java with [applicationinsights-agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent), when you develop in localhost and deploy the app in [some specific environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview#supported-environments-languages-and-resource-providers)(excluding azure app service). And as you mentioned that you wanna to log custom event like 'timestamp + user + actions', you need to add java appinsights sdk here.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>applicationinsights-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And you can add code like this and you can view it in portal:

[image]

[image]